# Injective function, $f:X\to X$ with $f(X)\subset X$, but $T\subseteq X$ is not inductive set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, peano-axioms

I'm looking for an example of the following manner:

Suppose that $f:X\to X$ is a injective function(where $X$ some set), such that the following property not holds:

If $T$ is subset of $X$, with the following two features: 
1. There is an element in $T$ that is not in the range of $f$
2. $t\in T$ implies that $f(t)\in T$. Then $T=X$.

Edit:

I'm trying to show that system that include three  of Peano's axioms is independent, in the following sense: that there exist set $X\neq\emptyset$ and function $f:X\to X$ such that the system with $X$ and $f$ satisfies two, and do nod holds for the third one. The set of axioms here is:

1. $f$ is a injective function;
2. $f(X)\subset X$;
3. The first principle of induction.

Comment: If f is bijective, how can there be a point, t, not in the range of f?

Comment: Right! My mistake; edited it to "injective".

Comment: I see the edit.  So f is injective, not bijective, fine.  What does "Then T = X" mean?

Comment: Wouldn't the natural numbers and $f(x)=2x$ and $T=\{1,2,4,8,...\}$ do?

Comment: I build that sort of an example, but I don't know if its acceptable here, as two condition holds and the conclusion($T=X$) is not.

Comment: I think the question needs clarification.

Comment: Ok, I think you are asking:  "Produce an example of an injective map , F, from some set X to itself such that, given any proper subset T of X, either T is contained in F(X) or F(T) is not contained in T."  Am I right?

Comment: But, if f is surjective then there is no T at all that meets your condition, hence the constraint is vacuously satisfied.  Do you also mean to require that f is not surjective?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

- $X=\{\langle a, b\rangle: a\in\mathbb{N}, b\in\{1, 2\}\}$ (so $X$ is basically two disjoint copies of $\mathbb{N}$)
- $f(\langle a, 1\rangle)=\langle 2a, 1\rangle$,
- $f(\langle a, 2\rangle)=\langle 2a+1, 1\rangle$.

Then $f$ is an injection from $X$ to itself, and $f(X)\subsetneq X$.

However, let $T=\{\langle a, 1\rangle: a\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\langle 17, 2\rangle\}.$ Then $t\in T\implies f(t)\in T$, and $\exists t\in T\forall x\in X(f(x)\not=t)$ (set $t=\langle 17, 2\rangle$); but $T\not=X$.

Comment: Nice! Interesting if there is a modification to set $X$, that instead to be a partial set $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$, $X$ would be a subset just of one copy of $\mathbb{N}$...

Comment: Well, we can do this with any countably infinite set by bijecting that set with $X$. The only reason I chose the $X$ I did was because it was cleanest.